# window.scrollTo(0, 240) not working with componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am building a website using Reactjs and Gatsby.

My problem is that I have `window.scrollTo(0, 240)` in `componentDidMount()`, if I refresh the site it works well. But when I use the Gatsby Link component, the website does not go to the set position.

I have also put a console.log which works fine to see if the function runs.

Furthermore I have run the `window.scrollTo(0,240)` directly in the browser console which also works fine.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'

import HeroHeader from "../components/HeroHeader"
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar"
import TopFooter from "../components/TopFooter"
import BottomFooter from "../components/BottomFooter"
import MainContent from "../components/MainContent"

class WebPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 240)
    console.log("Webpage Mounted")
  }

  render() {

    // window.scrollTo(0, 240)

    return(
      <>
        <HeroHeader />
        <NavBar />
        <MainContent>
          {this.props.children}
        </MainContent>
        <TopFooter />
        <BottomFooter />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default WebPage
```

Expecting to have each webpage scroll upon running the `componentDidMount()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it is possible to disable the `window.scroll(0, 0)` apparently built into Gatsby, using this guide: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-transitions/?=gatsby-plugin-transitions

Install the transition plugin:

`npm install --save yarn add gatsby-plugin-transitions gatsby-plugin-layout react-spring react react-dom`

*(Not actually sure how many of them is actually needed to simply disable the auto scroll).*

With this code in `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
exports.shouldUpdateScroll = () => {
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` executes only works on initial render, you should use `componentDidUpdate` which will execute on every re-render,

```
componentDidUpdate(){
   window.scrollTo(0, 240)
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, still nothing when I change pages. But I see my `console.log("Webpage Mounted")` and `console.log("Webpage Updated")` appear.

Comment: Means when you change page and come back to this page it is not triggering?

Comment: Yes, it is not triggered - Only first time entering the website. When clicking around the website, it should to every time when the "page" (a new `WebPage` component is loaded) is changed execute `window.scrollTo(0, 240)`.

Comment: Found out when I use the `window.scrollTo(0, 240)` in `componentDidUpdate()`. When I type into some form or something it executes...

Comment: Don't think I can recreate the code as it depends on Gatsby which does a lot of things in the background. But have I experimented with using `setTimeout( function () { window.scrollTo(0, 240) }, 100 )`. This makes the window scroll, but because of the delay it loads everyhing and then makes the scroll.

Comment: Also tried this in the `componentDidMount()`, which gave new insights:
`var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; while(top != 240) { console.log(top + " Whileloop"); window.scrollTo(0, 240); top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop } console.log(top + " Final")`
Console:
`0 Whileloop` then 
`240 Final`.
But nothing seems to happen. So I guess the function is executed, then the content is display and the scroll is reset somehow. But If I execute the function after 20ms it is possible to set the position. Just looks really jumpy.

Comment: Found out this was previously a bug: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3249. So there must be somewhere inside Gatsby the page scroll is reset... Probably some of this code is messing with me: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-react-router-scroll